# Istio CRD failed to install

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, kubernetes-helm, digital-ocean, istio

I am attempting to install `istio` in my DO K8s cluster.

I have created a null resource to download `istio` and run the helm charts using this example - https://mohsensy.github.io/sysadmin/2021/04/09/install-istio-with-terraform.html

TF looks like -

```
resource "kubernetes_namespace" "istio_system" {
  metadata {
    name = "istio-system"
  }
}

resource "null_resource" "istio" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<EOF
      set -xe

      cd ${path.root}
      rm -rf ./istio-1.9.2 || true
      curl -sL https://istio.io/downloadIstio | ISTIO_VERSION=1.9.2 sh -
      rm -rf ./istio || true
      mv ./istio-1.9.2 istio
    EOF
  }

  triggers = {
    build_number = timestamp()
  }
}

resource "helm_release" "istio_base" {
  name = "istio-base"
  chart = "istio/manifests/charts/base"

  timeout = 120
  cleanup_on_fail = true
  force_update = true
  namespace = "istio-system"

  depends_on = [
    digitalocean_kubernetes_cluster.k8s_cluster,
    kubernetes_namespace.istio_system,
    null_resource.istio
  ]
}
```

I can see the `istio` charts are downloaded with the CRDs.

```
│ Error: failed to install CRD crds/crd-all.gen.yaml: unable to recognize "": no matches for kind "CustomResourceDefinition" in version "apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1"
│ 
│   with helm_release.istio_base,
│   on istio.tf line 32, in resource "helm_release" "istio_base":
│   32: resource "helm_release" "istio_base" {
```

I need help in understanding what `unable to recognize ""` tells here!

I am looking for a resolution with some explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is trying to help you out:

```
unable to recognize "": no matches for kind "CustomResourceDefinition" in version "apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1"
```

Take a look at the API resources available in your Kubernetes enviornment:

```
$ kubectl api-resources | grep CustomResourceDefinition
```

You will probably see something like:

```
customresourcedefinitions             crd,crds                               apiextensions.k8s.io/v1                        false        CustomResourceDefinition
```

Note the API version there: it's `aspiextensions.k8s/io/v1`, not `/v1beta1`. Your manifest was built for an older version of Kubernetes. Changes are you can just change the `apiVersion` in the manifest to the correct value and it will work.

Comment: Ok! I got it! It's a version mismatch!